# What is the difference between Timer.Start and Timer.Enabled = True in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, timer

I'm wondering what the difference is between starting a timer and enabling a timer in vb.net?

Comment: Being pretty pedantic, one is a method and the other is a property. They're used for the same purpose, though, so you can think as either as synthatic sugar for the other.

Comment: Start() is the more 'honest' way. Enabled is not really 'honest'. After all you can enable something and not start it. With Start(), when you call it, the thing should be started.

Comment: Enabled, being a property, can be interrogated to determine whether the timer is currently active or not. I don't know of another way to tell whether a timer is currently raising elapsed events or not.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

They both do the same thing. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7dd5f0z7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Start Method

> Starts raising the Elapsed event by setting **Enabled** to **true**.