# Timer not executing second function on ElapsedEvent

Tags: c#, function, timer, console-application

I am trying to execute two function on a timer.
Opportunity() and Stakeholder()

However when I run the code for this:

```
    private static Timer myTimer;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting up...");
        myTimer = new Timer();
        myTimer.Interval = 60000;
        myTimer.Enabled = true;
        myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
        myTimer.Start();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("\nh:mm:ss tt") + " \n" + "Initiating...");
        Opportunities();
        Stakeholders();
    }
```

The Stakeholder(); function never executes. Only the first function (Opportunity()) is executed.

The two functions both retrieve data from web services and store them. Neither has a readline() or piece of code that prevents the function from completing.

Comment: Please show *all* the relevant code.  Opportunities, and stakeholders, etc.  Also, what happens in the debugger when you step through the code?

Comment: `timer.Start()` [is the same](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18644971/1997232) as `timer.Enabled = true`.

Comment: System.Timers.Timer is a very nasty class.  Any exception thrown in the Elapsed event handler is swallowed without any diagnostic.  You *must* use try/catch in your code.  Do favor System.Threading.Timer.  Albeit that you cannot use it the same way, you need a *static* variable so it can't be garbage-collected.